# Django version of Zend's Layouts?

Tags: php, python, django, zend-framework

Does Django have something like Zend's Layouts?
I use layouts in Zend a lot to provide the common elements of a website (I often call it the 'frame' around the content), e.g. the header, footer, etc. Then I render a view inside the layout to provide the custom content.

Is such a thing possible in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Zend, but from the sounds of what you are asking, you can use Django's [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/).

Basically you are going to create a base.html template that has your 'frame' and you can have other templates inherit from that.

Your base.html will look like

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}title{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}<br>
</body>
</html>
```

You can than have your 'child' templates look like:

```
{% extends "../templates/app/base.html"%}
{% block content %}
words on my page
{% endblock %}
```